# IntelliJ doesn't infer Stream.collect() type result

Tags: java, netbeans, intellij-idea, java-8, java-stream

This code works on Netbeans but gives an error on IntelliJ:

```
public static List<String> readFile(String file) throws IOException {
   Path path = Paths.get("src", file);
   Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path);
   return lines.collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

The error is on the `return` statement and says that a `List<String>` is expected but the `collect()` method gives a `List<Object>`.
It looks like that Netbeans is able to understand that a `Stream<String>` must be collected to a `List<String>` while IntelliJ isn't.

[image: The error]

What's the problem here?

EDIT: As suggested, I upgraded IntelliJ to the latest version (14.1.1) and I tried to compile my code with javac by terminal: it works. The problem must be in my IntelliJ configuration but it looks correct to me

Comment: Which version if IntelliJ are you using?

Comment: 14.0.3, Community Edition

Comment: Working fine for me so probably not an IntelliJ bug (I'm using the same version as you). Are you sure you are using the correct `toList()` import ?(because the first option of the auto-completion is to create your own toList method)

Comment: Look here: [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/OduJDio.png)

Comment: Actually I've just updated IntelliJ to 14.1.1, but I didn't remember having this kind of error (IntelliJ uses javac anyway afaik). What's your Java version? And what happens if you help the compiler by providing an explicit type parameter? `return lines.collect(Collectors.<String>toList());`

Comment: @user2336315 it works with the explicit type parameter! so it must be an IntelliJ bug... i will update it and test it again.
(i will mark your answer as correct if you post it)

Comment: @Oneiros And what happens if you compile your file with javac directly through command line? If the same error appears then you need to updgrade javac otherwise there is a problem with your IntelliJ configuration.

Comment: @user2336315 yes, it works with javac. It must be a problem with my IntelliJ configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the mistery: in `File Menu->Project Structure`, change `Project Language Level` to `8.0 - Lambdas, type annotations etc.`

Answer (score 2):

Why you are manually creating a `List<String>`? "There's an API for it." ;-)

Amend the snippet for your needs.

```
Path path = Paths.get("src", file);
Charset charset = Charset.defaultCharset();
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, charset);
```

**edit**

Have a look at the signature of your `toList()` method. I believe it's linked to that one.

if it's like

```
private static List<Object> toList() {
    return null;
}
```

you get in IntelliJ the error message you have posted: `Collector<? super String,Object,List<String>> in Stream cannot be applied to ListObject>`. Similar in Netbeans.

if it's like

```
static <T> Collector<T,?,List<T>> toList() {
    return null;
}
```

you get in IntelliJ the error `required: List<String> found: List<Object`. Whereas in Netbeans it compiles.

if it's like

```
static Collector<? super String, Object, List<String>> toList() {
    return null;
}
```

you don't get an error.

So as already mentioned it's linked to your `toList()` somehow. It would be interesting to know the type parameters for `new Collector(T, A, R)`.

Comment: While this is true, it doesn't answer the question. Also if you want to post improvements you should use comment, not answer.

Comment: exactly :D it works, but that error still looks weird to me (I will use your code anyway, thanks ;))

Comment: In that case it would also not work in NetBeans. I suspect that `toList()` comes from `Collectors` and was statically imported.

Comment: @SubOptimal `toList()`  is a collector, so its return type is different than that (actually the method signature looks like this `static <T> Collector<T,?,List<T>> toList()`). My thought at first would have been that the compiler would not have been able to infer the correct type but this was a long time ago, before compiler's improvements have been done. So your edit is not very useful.

Comment: @user2336315 is right, i'm using a static import: `import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;`

Answer (score 2):

You can help the compiler with an explicit type parameter:

```
return lines.collect(Collectors.<String>toList());
```

This was true some times ago but nowadays the work done to improve type inference on the compiler should make this type parameter unnecessary.

As far as I'm aware, IntelliJ uses javac behind the scenes, so your compile error is a bit weird.

Try also to compile your file with javac directly in command line and see if you have the same error.

If yes, then upgrade javac as soon as possible. If not, then there's certainly a problem in your IntelliJ configuration. Also you can upgrade IntelliJ to its latest 14.1.1 version.

Comment: I've just upgraded to the 14.1.1 version, the problem is still there. I checked again my configuration, I'm using javac and 1.8 JDK... this is very weird.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be, that your IntelliJ is not set up with Java 1.8 properly?

[Set the JDK for IntelliJ](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23455956-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under). It probably points to an older Java Version

Comment: It is the first thing that came to my mind, but it looks correctly setted

Comment: If it didn't point to the correct Java version, I guess he would have the error on the Stream line instead.